# How to setup maven-site-plugin when aggregator is not the parent?

Tags: maven-3, maven-site-plugin

I have a system that has a pom aggregator grouping some modules.

I'm using maven-site 3.3 and maven 3.2.1.

One of those module is a parent whose parent is a corporate pom that are built in another job.

- Root-Aggregator

  - parent-pom

    - component-one
    - component-two
  - component-three

I've setup different values for the project.url and site.url for each project, where root-aggregator is the root and parent is under it.

The problem that I'm facing now is that both Root-Aggregator and parent-pom are being copied (stage) to the same root folder (stagingDirectory). So the last project are overriding the files from parent-pom.

```
[INFO] Pushing /home/cvgaviao/aggregator-maven/maven.parent/target/site
[INFO]    >>> to file:///home/cvgaviao/Development/STAGING-SITE/./


[INFO] Pushing /home/cvgaviao/aggregator-maven/target/site
[INFO]    >>> to file:///home/cvgaviao/Development/STAGING-SITE/./
```

How to make maven-site-plugin to understand that the parent pom is not the root ?